# What is responsible for changing core's load and frequency in multicore processor

Tags: operating-system, multicore, processor

Having looked for a description of the multicore design i keep finding several diagrams, but all of them look somewhat like this:

[image: multicore design]

I know from looking at `i7z` command output that different cores can run at different frequencies.

This would suggest that the decisions regarding which core will be given a new process and for changing the frequency of the core itself are done either by the operating system or by the control block of the core itself.

My question is: What controls the frequencies of each individual core? Is the job of associating a `READY` process with the specific core placed upon the operating system or is it done by something within the processor.

Comment: @xmojmr I've tried several PDFs from the link you provided. They all that Figure 3-9, but not the one you described. Can you please tell me which one you mean?

Comment: open http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf (_Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B and 3C_), ctrl+F "_Algorithm for Extracting Processor Frequency_"

Comment: @xmojmr All the models discussed there (as seen in the table lower than that diagram) deal with the single-core processors. So it doesn't really help.

Comment: You should consider to change you diagram and put the text in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduling processes/threads to cores is purely [up to the OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Short-term_scheduling).  The hardware has no understanding of tasks waiting to run.  Maintaining the OS's list of processes that are runnable vs. waiting for I/O is completely a software thing.

Migrating a thread from one core to another is done by kernel code on the original core storing the [architectural state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_state) to memory, then OS code on the new core restoring that saved state and resuming user-space execution.

Traditionally, frequency and voltage scaling decisions are made by the OS.  Take Linux as an example:  The decision-making code is called a [governor](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt) (and also this [arch wiki link came up high on google](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling)).  It looks at things like how often processes have used their entire [time slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice) on the current core.  If the governor decides the CPU should run at a different speed, it programs some control registers to implement the change.  As I understand it, the hardware takes care of choosing the [right voltage to support the requested frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).

As I understand it, the OS running on each core makes decisions independently.  On hardware that allows each core to run at different frequencies, the decision-making code doesn't need to coordinate with each other.  If running a high frequency on one core requires a high voltage chip-wide, the hardware takes care of that.  I think the modern implementation of DVFS (dynamic voltage and frequency scaling) is fairly high-level, with the OS just telling the hardware which of N choices it wants, and the onboard power microcontroller taking care of the details of programming oscillators / clock dividers and voltage regulators.

Intel's "Turbo" feature, which opportunistically boosts the frequency above the max sustainable frequency, does the decision making in hardware.  Any time the OS requests the highest advertised frequency, the CPU uses turbo when power and cooling allow.

Intel's Skylake takes this a step further: The OS can hand full control over DVFS to the hardware, optionally with constraints.  That lets it react from microsecond to microsecond, rather than on a timescale of milliseconds.  This does actually allow better performance in bursty workloads, because more power budget is available for turbo when it's useful.  A few benchmarks are bursty enough to observe this, like some browser / javascript ones IIRC.

**There was a whole talk about Skylake's new power management at IDF2015**, [check out the slides and/or archived webcast](http://myeventagenda.com/sessions/0B9F4191-1C29-408A-8B61-65D7520025A8/7/5#sessionID=155).  The old method is described in a lot of detail there, too, to illustrate the difference, so you should really check it out if you want more detail than my summary.  (The list of other IDF talks is [here](http://myeventagenda.com/sessions/0B9F4191-1C29-408A-8B61-65D7520025A8/7/5), thanks to [Agner Fog's blog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415) for the link)

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty sure that this is going to be an accepted answer, but let me take some tome to absorb all the info that you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

The core frequency is controlled by a given voltage applied to a core's "oscillator".

This voltage can be changed by the Operating System but it can also be changed by the BIOS itself if a high temperature is detected in the CPU.

Comment: I have given you a bounty, since you have answered most of the question. But could you please explain something. OS wants to send the command to the oscillator, what is really happening is that this command is loaded to be executed. Does it need to be loaded into the core that will be changed or will any core do (can any core send the command to the oscillator of another core or does the OS load the command into the specific core for execution).

Comment: Volodya, unfortunately I do not know precisely the answer for this question. However, based on my knowledge of PC architecture, my bet is that any core can do the job.

Comment: @v010dya these processes are completely independent, so any core could do it. In fact, the answer is not simple as there are a lot of things happening.
The OS generates a "request", that is passed to the respective controllers (through the drivers). Then the controllers do "their job". But the frequency can also be changed without intervention of the OS. For example (simplified) - a "BIOS" (it is not a BIOS, but for simplicity...) changes frequency based on the load of the core. In this case the OS loads the core, yes, but has no real controll over the CPU. etc...