# Why is the performance of a running program getting better over time?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86-64

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using Time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using us = std::chrono::microseconds;

int main()
{
    volatile int i, k;
    const int n = 1000000;

    for(k = 0; k < 200; ++k) {
            auto begin = Time::now();
            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i);  // <--
            auto end = Time::now();
            auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<us>(end - begin).count();
            std::cout << dur << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am repeatedly measuring the execution time of the inner *for loop*.
The results are shown in the following plot (y: duration, x: repetition):

[image]

What is causing the decreasing of the loop execution time?

Environment: *linux (kernel 4.2) @ Intel i7-2600*, compiled using: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -O0 -o main`

**Edit 1**

The question is **not about compiler optimization or performance benchmarks**.
The question is, why the performance gets better over time.
I am trying to understand what is happening at run-time.

**Edit 2**

As proposed by *Vaughn Cato*, I have changed the CPU frequency scaling policy to "**Performance**". Now I am getting the following results:

[image]

It confirms *Vaughn Cato*'s conjecture. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: If I were `g++`, I would compile your inner loop to the equivalent of `i = n`.

Comment: I test in my computer, and the result show that the time is always 2000 less or more, and the range is less than 250.

Comment: Benchmarking without optimizations is meaningless.

Comment: @barry - that statement does not make any sense.

Comment: @Barry I can't follow, could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I get behavior like this on some runs, and on other runs, the times are pretty consistent.

Comment: @sergej You're not compiling with optimizations. That is, the compiler isn't making any real effort at improving performance. If you compiled with `-O3`, the inner loop would disappear completely. That's the only realistic thing to benchmark

Comment: Maybe it is throttling.

Comment: @Barry Please see the edit. I don't want the inner loop to disappear. I am trying to understand what is happening at run-time.

Comment: Do you run your code from console or from an IDE (i.e. CPU sharing with other processes that get less active) and do you have any other processes open ?

Comment: @sergej Perhaps you should declare to us, "This is not benchmarking." Otherwise, the idea of "Benchmarking code should be optimized" will be emphasized again and again to you.

Comment: I can't reproduce http://ideone.com/D8G6x7

Comment: @barry - If the compiler does or does not optimise it produces machine code. The question is why this machine code performance gets better over time.

Comment: @Christophe The first runs take longer in your example as well.

Comment: I made a variant storing values in a preallocated vector instead of output to avoid bias from the console, and indeed, the average is slightly lover for the 30 last than for the 30 first everytime I run it:  http://ideone.com/oDTWl0

Comment: @sergej, yes but only the first, and this may be related to the initialisation of online console.  I therefore made a second version without console (see my comment above), and indeed, the observation can be confirmed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are probably seeing is CPU frequency scaling (throttling).  The CPU goes into a low-frequency state to save power when it isn't being heavily used.

Just before running your program, the CPU clock speed is probably fairly low, since there is no big load.  When you run your program, the busy loop increases the load, and the CPU clock speed goes up until you hit the maximum clock speed, decreasing your times.

If you run your program several times in a row, you'll probably see the times stay at a lower value after the first run.

Comment: You are right, see the edit. It seems so obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: That's a bit odd, I thought the governor would normally jump to max and then back off if that proved faster than needed.  IIRC, that's what skylake does when it's given full control of DVFS.  ([See Intel's presentation on SKL power/turbo](http://myeventagenda.com/sessions/0B9F4191-1C29-408A-8B61-65D7520025A8/7/5#sessionID=155).  (@sergej: Also see [this for other relevant links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889991/what-is-responsible-for-changing-cores-load-and-frequency-in-multicore-processo/36234129#36234129))

Answer (score 1):

In you original experiment, there are too many variables than can affect the measurements:

- the use of your processor by other active processes (i.e. scheduling of your OS)
- The question whether your loop is optimized away or not
- The access and buffering to the console.
- The initial mode of your CPU (see answer about throtling)

I must admit that I was very skeptical about your observations.  I therefore wrote a small variant using a preallocated vector, to avoid I/O synchronisation effects:

```
volatile int i, k;  
const int n = 1000000, kmax=200,n_avg=30;
std::vector<long> v(kmax,0); 

for(k = 0; k < kmax; ++k) {
        auto begin = Time::now();
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i);  // <-- remain thanks to volatile
        auto end = Time::now();
        auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<us>(end - begin).count();
        v[k]=dur;  
}
```

I then ran it several times on ideone (which, given the scale of its use, we can assume that in average the processor whould be in a constantly sollicitated state).  Indeed your observations seemed to be confirmed.

I guess that this could be related to **[branch prediction](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nehalem-microprocessor-microarchitecture3.htm)**, which should improve through the repetitive patterns.

I however went on, updated the code slightly and added a loop to [repeat the experiment](http://ideone.com/oDTWl0) several times. Then I started to get also runs where your observation was not confirmed (i.e. at the end, the time was higher). But it may also be that the many other processes running on the ideone also influence the branch prediction in a different manner.

So in the end, to conclude anything would require a more cautious experiment, on a machine running this benchmark (and only it) a couple of hours.